# Creating Contours in Feet?

Tags: qgis, contour

I'm fairly new to QGIS and GIS altogether. I'm curious if it's possible to generate contours from a DEM in feet, as opposed to meters. I'm hoping to then have my labels in feet.

Comment: If you multiply the meters values by 0.3048, you'll have feet, but if you want whole-number foot contours, you'd need to multiply the DEM by 0.3048, then create new contours.

Comment: What software do you use? QGIS?